# Excel VBA table manipulation: transpose column based on first column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to organize a table generated by importing from multiple text files.  Importing the multiple text files into excel creates a table similar to the dataset below. It has the text file name in column A and the values are in Column B.

1. Number of groups is around 400
2. Number of "IDs" is always 160
3. Using a formula would be great, but I figured that wouldn't be possible

Here is my data set.
It has only two columns as described but needs to be transposed so that there is one row per distinct column 1 entry, which will then have multiple columns:

```
|Group|Value|
|-----|-----|
|A.txt| 1a  |
|A.txt| 2a  |
|A.txt| 3a  |
|B.txt| 1b  |
|B.txt| 2b  |
|B.txt| 3b  |
|C.txt| 1c  |
|C.txt| 2c  |
|C.txt| 3c  |
```

Here's the desired result!

```
|Group|ID1|ID2|ID3|
|:----|:-:|:-:|--:|
|A.txt|1a |2a |3a |
|B.txt|1b |2b |3b |
|C.txt|1c |2c |3c |
```

The number of IDs are the same for each entry.

I have used VBA in excel many years ago, but I haven't since 2015!  Needing some help.

Comment: how many groups are we talking about? Are they changing (the unique names)? Does it  have to be VBA? If a formula can do it ?

Comment: Hello @Apostolos55, I had updated my post to answer your questions.  Can you clarify what you mean by unique names?  If you mean ID1, ID2, ID3 than let me point out that those values are not provided in the data set and can be left empty.

Comment: Hello again StackOverflow community.  This question has unfortunately has a -3 score, but I'm having trouble understanding why.  Is this too complex of problem to be solved within Excel?  My thought process is to transpose the values until Group changes and than to start a new transpose for the next Group.  Please point me in a direction that will allow me to solve this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up.  It took me a year to have 3 hours to work on this project.  I'll likely at some point in the near future extend this to sort and use VLOOKUP(), but this exercise was the starting point I needed to remember how to use VBA.

This is a first draft requiring to create a button, but will have VBA load a each of the txt files from a folder and create the initial set than run the macro below against that.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim group As Integer
Dim str1 As String
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    str1 = ""
    group = 0
    j = 0
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To 10
        If str1 = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            k = k + 1
            Cells(group, 4 + k).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Else
            str1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
            If group = 0 Then
                Cells(1, 4).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
                j = j + 1
            Else
                Cells(1, 4 + group).Value = CStr(group)
                Cells(group + 1, 4).Value = str1
                Cells(group + 1, 4 + j).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
            group = group + 1
            k = 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for an Excel/VBA solution, but I will give you a very easy Google Sheets one. You can easily open you Excel over at goolge  sheets and work there. You may even get the Idea and port it to Excel then.
Just put in the same places and write the formulas at the assigned cells, or adjust the formulas...

[image]

I paste the code here as well:

```
D2: =UNIQUE(A2:A)
E1: = ARRAYFORMULA("ID" & TEXT(SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(E2:2),1,1),"00"))
E2: =TRANSPOSE( filter($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A=$D2))
e3... drag down from E2
```

Comment: Thank you the ARRAYFORMULA is very useful; however I'm looking to not load anything on the cloud.